# Calendar setTimeInMillis returns the same day and year no matter what unix time is put in

Tags: android, unix, android-fragments, calendar, timestamp

So I'm facing a weird issue with Calendar I've never encountered. Heres the situation, I'm getting certain posts from a server that include a createdDateTime set in a long value in UNIX time.

When I print these values out and check them on a UNIX converter the date is returned correctly but in the list the calendar is returned with the day 17 and year 1970 no matter what.

Here is my Fragment that sets the adapter, I tried two different ways, one with the adapter in a separate class and one with the adapter in the fragment:
also PostDM is a class storing the values of the post.

FIRST WAY SEPARATE CLASS:

```
public static class AllFragment extends TopFragment{
    ArrayList<PostDM> allIncidents = new ArrayList<PostDM>();
    AllIncidentAdapter allIncidentAdapter;
    ListView list;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);
        list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.all_list);
        getAllIncidents(); //this service works fine, i'd rather not show it, 
                           //the value for createdDateTime is set and the converter shows its 1/8/2015
        allIncidentAdapter = new AllIncidentAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_all_list, allIncidents);
        list.setAdapter(allIncidentAdapter);
        return v;
    }
}
```

ADAPTER:

```
public class AllIncidentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PostDM>{
    ArrayList<PostDM> post;
    int layoutResourceId;
    Activity activity;
    String[] months = { "Jan.", "Feb.", "Mar.", "Apr.", "May", "June", "July",
        "Aug.", "Sept.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Dec." };
    public AllIncidentAdapter(Activity activity, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<PostDM> post){
        super(activity, layoutResourceId, post);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.post = post;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            v = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);

            // viewHolder ids are found but I didnt want to include them here 

            v.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        v.getTag();
        PostDM p = post.get(position);
        if(p!=null){
            Calendar calendar = calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(p.createdDateTime);
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            String date = months[month]+" "+day+", "+year;
            viewHolder.date.setText(date);
        }
    }
    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView user, date, address, type, message, number, comments, status;
        ImageView uploadedImage, userImage;
        Button uploadImage;
        EditText addComment;
    }
}
```

this is the way I'd prefer to keep it so I can keep my fragment from growing to large line wise.

Both ways gave me the same result though, the long value for one I got back is 1420678690.
The UNIX converter i used at unixtimestamp.com/index.php gave me 01/08/2015 but when I set the date text I get Jan. 17, 1970 for every value, no matter the timestamp.

Any Idea what I could be doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT ANSWERED:

Thanks to Mike M. he helped me figure the issue out, apparently I was working with seconds and not milliseconds. So multiplying the value createdDateTime by 1000 solved the issue and gave me the correct date.

Comment: Looks like you're dealing in seconds, not milliseconds. That is, multiply the value you're getting from the server by 1000.

Comment: You might find this helpful. http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: thanks Mike! that worked perfectly! It's always the little things.